# Keep old VS project when migrating to new controls suite or not?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, user-controls, telerik, integration, infragistics

The project I’m working on is revamping an existing web portal.

Migration from the old controls (Infragistics) to a new suite (Telerik) is part of the revamp.

Would you recommend to keep the old Visual studio project and put the new controls in or starting a new VS project altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much you are using the third party controls and what portion of your site it is.  If it is a small portion it may be better to continue with the existing project.  If you have very heavy usage of the third party controls that you are removing on each page a rewrite may be easier.

If you are looking at possibly rewriting using a new project you may also want to consider the technology that you are using as well.  For example if you were using ASP.NET Web Forms before, maybe it would make sense to use ASP.NET MVC now.

I believe the best answer to your question is that you need to evaluate what you are using and the amount of work that each approach will require and determine what is best for your specific scenario.